# Best practice to handle ajax jquery database queries?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a "little" problem because I don't know whats the best way to handle ajax jquery database request?

So far I've done it this way:
For ever (single) database request I created a new .php file like:

```
newbill.php
newcosumer.php
listallbills.php
updatecostumer.php
```

..and so on and pull the data via:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/newbill.php",
    data: "..."
    success: function(msg){    
    ...
    }
 });
```

..what I don't like is all the .php files for only ONE! database request!?
There must be a better way to handle this??

Comment: What is your particular problem?

Comment: This is not a jquery question.  This is really about server side patterns and implementation.  If you add the PHP tag to your post, you'll probably get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in this way.

Create a php file for each entity (Ex : consumerajax.php , billajax.php,etc...) then have seperate functions for each of your database queries.When calling from the javascript pass a querystring variable to determine which function to be executed in the ajax server page

Ex : In consumerajax.php

```
 <?php

    $mode= $_GET["mode"] ;
    if($mode=="getconsumerdet")
    {
       $consumerId=$_GET["cid"];
       GetConsumerDetails($consumerId)
    }
    else if($mode=="updateconsumer")
    {
      $consumerId=$_GET["cid"];
      $name=$_GET["name"];
      UpdateConsumerInfo($consumerId, $name)
    }

    function GetConsumerDetails($consumerId)
    {
       // execute query the table here and return the result from here
      echo"Have the data and return"
    } 
    function UpdateConsumerInfo($consumerId,$name)
    {
      //execute query to update
     echo "updated";
    }

?>
```

and from your scrip call like

```
  $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "ajax/consumerajax.php?mode=getconsumerdet&cid=34", data: "..." success: function(msg){   });
```

or

```
  $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "ajax/consumerajax.php?mode=updateconsumer&cid=34&name=shyju", data: "..." success: function(msg){   });
```

Comment: thx, thats it, I was thinking about something like that too (with this kind of helper variable=$mode) but thought there might be a better way to address the functions(or methods in a class) directly somehow??

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single file called ie. `dbrequest.php` and pass it parameters, that you then read from php and make the appropriate request to the database..

But it would depend on what exactly you are doing inside your pages, and if it is easy to maintain in a single file..

Comment: My Idea was to have a Datamanager Class for the DB Queries but maybe a plain scriptfile with functions will do (as Shyju showed)? Why do it complicated when it can be simple :)